# Decrypting an RSA message given $a^2 \equiv 1 \pmod n$

Tags: rsa, modular-arithmetic, factoring, rabin-cryptosystem, quadratic-residuosity

I need help with a practice problem for an upcoming test. I've learned the answer to the problem is "well done", but don't know how to get there. Any help is greatly appreciated.

> Suppose that the RSA modulus of $n := 42313421$ used with an encryption exponent of $2015$ produces the pair $(27285537, 25251845)$ of ciphertexts. Use the fact that
>
> $26437093^2 ≡ 1 \pmod n$
>
> to find the original plaintext message. Show your work.

I don't see how fact stated helps with the problem.

Comment: Hint: You know two different pairs of square-roots of the same number ($\pm1$ and $\pm26437093$ all square to $1$) which allows you to factor $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider two numbers $a$ and $b$ that square to the same value modulo $n$ and don't just differ by the sign.

$$a^2 \equiv b^2 \pmod n2$$ 
$$(a-b)(a+b) \equiv 0 \pmod n$$

Neither of the factors on the left is 0 (or equivalently a multiple of $n$), thus each of them must contain one of the prime factors of $n$.

Thus you can use $\operatorname{GCD}(a-b, n)$ and $\operatorname{GCD}(a+b, n)$ to recover factors of $n$. If $n$ is the product of two primes, you thus factored $n$. Once you factored $n$, follow the standard RSA key generation procedure to obtain the decryption exponent $d$.

In your example $a=\pm 1$ and $b=\pm 26437093$.

---

This attack is important in the context of the [Rabin cryptosystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin_cryptosystem), which works like RSA, except it uses the public exponent $2$. So the decrypter/signer has to make sure that they never produce information about different roots for a given square, otherwise an attacker can recover their public key.